# Scale up UIView with UIImage without affecting resolution of UIImage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, scaling

My problem is when I'm scaling up my `UIView`'s background image it gets anti-aligning and very blurry although the original image is in high resolution and very bright.

The process of scaling happens when I make an animation on the `UIView` to scale it. I'm scaling `UIView` using the transform property of `UIView`.

The code I'm using to make the `UIImage` fit into new scale is:

```
-(UIImage *)imageResize :(UIImage*)image withSize:(CGSize)size
{

    CGSize newSize = self.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

And I'm assigning the background color with this line:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self imageResize:img withSize:(CGSize)size]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to apply screen resolution in this line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
```

Should look like this

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, screenScale);
```